# RestTemplate getForEntity Method 405 Error

Tags: microservices

Using RestTemplate getForEntity method to invoke Microservices running on Port 8444 from Port 8443 but getting below error: 
 Using PostMan -->POST-->http://localhost:8443/company/cases/INX CORP LTD

```
Error
{
  "timestamp": "2019-08-25T13:44:05.939+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "405 null",
  "path": "/company/cases/INX CORP LTD"
}



RestController
@RequestMapping("/company")
public class CompanyCaseController {

@Autowired
private CompanyCaseService companyCaseService;

@PostMapping(path = "/cases/{companyName}")
public @ResponseBody
Page<ConfonetCases> getCases(@PathVariable String companyName, @RequestBody Map<String, Integer> pagination){
LocalDateTime startTime = LocalDateTime.now();
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pagination.get("page"), pagination.get("size"));


Page<ConfonetCases> cases = companyCaseService.getCases(companyName, pageable);
List<ConfonetCases> confonetCases = new ArrayList<>();


companyCaseService.getCases(companyName, pageable).stream()
    .forEach(confonetCases1 -> {
        if (confonetCases1.getNextHearingDate() == null) {

            Map<String, String> paramsMap = new HashMap<>();
            paramsMap.put("companyName", companyName);
            paramsMap.put("pagination", "NONE");


            ResponseEntity<Judgement> judgementResponseEntity = new RestTemplate().getForEntity("http://localhost:8444/company/judgement/{companyName}",
                                                                                                Judgement.class, paramsMap);

            // Make RestTemplate call call and get judgement for the given case confonetCases1
            confonetCases1.setOrderDate(judgementResponseEntity.getBody().getDateOfDisposal());
            confonetCases1.setJudgementUrl(judgementResponseEntity.getBody().getJudgementURL());
        } else {

            //Make RestTemplate call to get History foe the given case confonetCases1
            //confonetCases1.setNextHearingDate(history.getNextHearingDate);
        }
        confonetCases.add(confonetCases1);

    });


Page<ConfonetCases> Conftcases = new PageImpl<ConfonetCases>(confonetCases,pageable,cases.getNumberOfElements());
LocalDateTime endTime = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println("Time Difference: " + Duration.between(startTime, endTime).getSeconds());
return cases;
}
}



@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/company")
public class CompanyJudgementController {

    @Autowired
    private JudgementService judgementService ;

   @PostMapping(path = "/judgement/{companyName}")
    public @ResponseBody
    Page<Judgement> getJudgements(@PathVariable String companyName, @RequestBody String pagination){

        System.out.println("Inside getJudgements method..............................>>>>");
        LocalDateTime startTime = LocalDateTime.now();

        Map<String, Integer> pageMap = new HashMap();
        pageMap.put("page", 0);
        pageMap.put("size", 20);

        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageMap.get("page"), pageMap.get("size"));

        Page<Judgement> judgements = judgementService.getJudgements(companyName, pageable);
        LocalDateTime endTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        System.out.println("Time Difference: " + Duration.between(startTime, endTime).getSeconds());
        return judgements;
    }
}
```

Firt Method is getCases() is calling getJudgements() method from another microservices, but its throwing 405 null error

Answer (score 0):

405 Method Not Allowed :The API responds with a 405 error to indicate that the client tried to use an HTTP method that the resource does not allow.

> A 405 response must include the Allow header, which lists the HTTP
>   methods that the resource supports. For example:
>
> Allow: GET, POST

Add try catch block on rest template call andcheck stack trace.

```
        ResponseEntity<Judgement> judgementResponseEntity = new RestTemplate().getForEntity("http://localhost:8444/company/judgement/{companyName}",
```

Removed {companyName} and pass company name dynamically .